# How to receive and map dynamic URLS using Prismic and Server Side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, prismic.io

I have an app using Create Next App with SSR using the Prismic API as a content source.  I am trying to create dynamic routes and running into a brick wall.  Singleton routes were fine but trying to dynamically create routes I can't seem to figure it out.

My Component where I wait to recieve props

```
class AboutPage extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps(context) {
    const { slug } = context.query;
    const response = await getAboutPage(slug);
    return {
      doc: response,
      slices: response.results[0].data.body,
      data: response.results[0].data,
    };
  }
```

My query where I attempt to get my page data based off the UID:

```
const getAboutPage = slug => {
  try {
    const API = Prismic.api(PRISMIC_API_URL);
    const response = API.query([
      Prismic.Predicates.at('document.tags', [SOURCE]),
      Prismic.Predicates.at('my.about_page.uid', slug),
    ]);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

My Prismic Link Resolver, but not sure this is relevant

```
function linkResolver(doc) {
  if (doc.type === 'home_page') return `/`;
  if (doc.type === 'pricing_page') return `/pricing`;
  if (doc.type === 'service_page') return `/services/${doc.uid}`;
  if (doc.type === 'about_page') return `/${doc.uid}`;
  if (doc.type === 'resource_page') return `/resources/${doc.uid}`;
  return '/';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions from the fact that you're using Create Next App, I think a probable cause is that you're not passing the query to the component because you're using the `next` command for your development environment, which won't support direct navigation with custom routing.
If I'm right, creating some links to those pages using Next's `<Link>` component you should be able to navigate to your generated pages on the client side.

The official [recommendations detailed by Zeit](https://zeit.co/guides/custom-next-js-server-to-routes/) and their [step-by-step tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/server-side-support-for-clean-urls/setup) detail that you need to either set up a node Express app to handle the custom routing, or setting up the routing information in a `now.json` configuration file. This will pass the query information so they can be used in `getInitialProps`.

Basically, to get started quickly you will replace the `dev` command in `package.json` to be Nodejs instead of Nextjs. I should also mention that `now dev` [has been announced](https://zeit.co/blog/now-dev) which should provide a development environment without the need for an extra node server app.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That solved it.  I had tried a custom server but didnt correct my npm script.